# Out-Of-Queue Review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The "Review Queues" are probably fine the way they are; however I find them hard to use because as it pops me through the queue I don't feel very "expert" enough to make an opinion on what I'm reading...

Would it be possible/desirable to add the same review functionality outside the queue to Q&A's that I'm browsing through? (share/edit/follow/flag/"review")

Comment: Do you mean show pending review tasks on all posts outside of /review? Similar to how suggested edits can be reviewed from the post itself but for all queues?

Comment: This would also inherently increase the number of people reviewing posts, if posts in review were directly reviewable by people who happen to cross them in the wild.

Comment: Side-note: you can add a filter to the queue if you want to review only tasks from given tags.

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to change. You can already vote, flag and comment on posts directly; most review tasks do similar or even the same things. What additional tools do you have in mind?

Comment: @VLAZ that didn't seem to help much since mostly my reviews are domain knowledge based vs the tags which are not

Comment: Another note: this is possible with suggested edit reviews. They can be actioned directly from a post which has a suggestion pending. So, the FR has some basis already.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see one benefit if you could go directly to the rewiew queue. Suppose one finds a question which is in the Triage queue. If they flag it outside the queue it will still need at least three reviewers in Triage while if they could go to the queue, their flag would count there.

Comment: The other benefit is that dismissing review tasks is not currently possible when things are OK. I don't believe that "Looks OK" reviews can be cleared outside of queue by any of the standard actions mentioned (vote, flag, comment, etc).

Comment: This is very unlikely to happen in practice. SE has gone to extreme lengths to hide away most review tasks, except suggested edits. Unfinished reviews showing up in the timeline has been considered a bug in the past as well

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I wonder why they were doing this. Getting more expert reviews sounds like a good thing to me, especially given the current reviewer shortage? When I read a post and evaluate whether I can answer it or not, I may just handle corresponding reviews while I'm at it. Has there been some abuse in the past?

Comment: @janw I have no idea. Haven't been around long enough to know if there's a reason, if there was one stated in public anyway. You'd probably have to ask SE

Comment: @janw "Getting more reviews" would be the end result, expert or not. Part of the problem we have in the queues are people not paying enough attention. If they access it without the benefit of audits, there is no mechanism for controlling those "robo-reviewers".

Comment: @HereticMonkey to audit the post level review. The link could take you to the post where it lives in the q, and/or present with an option to add/request to add(rep based?) it to a q.

Comment: If you don't feel like you can review the contribution properly, then you should skip the review of the contribution, instead of choosing to review something you don't feel comfortable with.  However, it does not actually take knowledge to review the quality of contributions and determine if something meets the community guidelines does not require a ton of domain knowledge IMO.  Does it make it easier, I suppose, but you can also get that by reviewing more contributions.

Comment: @SecurityHound I guess one of the things I'm trying to avoid, is that I skip so many that it starts to feel like why should I even bother looking at the queue.

Answer (score -10):

I'm going to disagree with this feature request because I don't understand *this* rationale.

> I find [the review queues] hard to use because as it pops me through the queue I don't feel very "expert" enough to make an opinion on what I'm reading...

How does that change depending on where you're reading the question or answer?  The only difference with doing the review in-situ versus the queue sounds like you don't have a convention to "skip" the review (which is what we should all be doing if we don't feel confident enough to review the question or answer), which would lead to more, *worse* reviews (which is expressly what we want to avoid).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with OP's apparent perception that it's easier to review posts where you're an SME. This may not necessarily be true for all queues, but I imagine that this notion is more or less why the filter function exists in the review queues in the first place.

Comment: You are correct in that where the Q or A is read doesn't change the post itself; however what does change is who discovers the post. I find that I am more likely to see a post that I would be able to point out as obviously needing a review through my natural usage of SE then I am by skipping through the queue until something stands out. While the review queue can filter quite well for tech I'm familiar with, it rarely presents to me posts that are on topics I have experience in.