# Tell users when their edits are rejected

Tags: feature-request, status-review, suggested-edits, notifications

The [edit queue is up for discussion again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/reviewer-overboard-or-a-request-to-improve-the-onboarding-guidance-for-new-revi?cb=1).

I have a different feature request: **Tell new editors when their edit suggestions are rejected.**

When I first started editing on Stack Overflow, I was delighted that there was finally a way I could contribute to Stack Overflow and earn some points towards upvote or comment privileges.  It seemed -- to my naive perspective -- that it even allowed for a workaround to the fact that commenting was blocked.

So I started editing.  After a few weeks and several edits, I noticed (in a minor tab of my profile page) that the majority of my edits had been rejected.  So I changed my editing habits.  Suggesting edits takes time, and as a new user, I want ALL of my edits to be accepted.  Score or otherwise, I don't want to develop a low accepted-edit score.

If I had received a notification of my rejected edit (similar to the top-right notifications of messages and reputation score changes), I would have begun to incorporate community feedback immediately and saved reviewers the trouble of reviewing my earlier edits.

This may be a moderately-expensive feature to implement, but I think it will be worth it. Newer reviewers will be happier because they will not have the unpleasant surprise of seeing several edits rejected at once.  And edit-queue reviewers will be happier because they have 5x or 10x fewer bad edits per new user.

Comment: it could *also* have the opposite effect of users becoming upset at being notified their work is being rejected, even in cases where it's just a one-off that won't matter in the grand scheme of things. Transparency is generally good, but it can also result in a bunch of nitpicking in cases where it just isn't worth the scrutiny.

Comment: It's not uncommon that we have to mod-message people to get them stop suggesting a particular class of bad edits.  This seems like a decent idea, even if it means a bit more handling of griping.  Perhaps we'll eventually need to hide the reviewer names from people viewing their own suggested edit rejections, similar to how we do for question closure, but we can also cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe the system could warn users when there are several recent rejections, kind of like we do with flags. So the user isn't getting pinged for one offs but does get warned when there's a pattern.

Comment: I vaguely remember some sort of warning message being displayed to users when they try to suggest an edit after having several suggestions rejected. Does/did this exist or is it just my imagination?