Show rejections in the achievements-dialog as the current implementation is highly inefficient
Currently, when a user raises flags or submits suggest-edits, they will not be notified in the achievements-dialog should any of them be rejected.
TLDR: Instead when raising a new flag/making a new suggest-edit, there is an info-box telling that the last edit/flag has been rejected. But especially on the edit-dialogue, this can be overlooked, a concern already raised. This is a problem, as the user may not realize that and therefore will continue to do the same mistake when curating/flagging content.

The issue stems from the implementation for the feature request "https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420487/tell-users-when-their-edits-are-rejected" was to change the text in the info box at the edit window titled:

"Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed."

When one has a rejected review, it reads:

"Attention! Your last edit was rejected While reasonable edits may be rejected for man reasons outside of your content, you should review the reasons given for rejecting it before continuing."

instead of

"We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks."

The title stays the same.
Not only is the text not really helpful, but it is more importantly: it is unnoticeable. After the first edit, I knew what was in the box above and the "How to edit" box in the side, so I never really pay attention to it.
To visualize, this is what an editor sees (Curtsey of dba.stackexchange as there are too many pending edits as of writing):

Further due to how the review queue works I can have an edit be rejected and then have another approved which to my knowledge means the warning does not show up.
This all leads to new editors doing the same mistake again and again.
At this point the reader might be wondering: If this is all so bad, why did they not choose to show rejection it in the notification as with approved edits as?
The official reason is:

"We believe this is a better user experience than inbox notifications because the potential for discouraging users from suggesting edits in the future is lower. Receiving an inbox notification saying you did something wrong at any given time (likely not while editing) would have a more negative impact on most users than reading a notice while they are actively in the flow of editing."

If that were true, we should also remove notifications for downvotes/closures and only notify them that they got downvoted while they are actively in the flow of writing another post.
This could easily be prevented by having the achievements-dialog show rejections, thereby making the user actively aware of an error. The user can then check as to why and (hopefully) not repeat that mistake.

While at it, I'd like to bring attention to the proposal 'Allow adding a custom rejection reason when marking an edit as "Reject and Edit"', as that could further help to bring new editors up to speed on how to edit.

I'm more thinking about the achievements icon, similar to how reputation change is handled. The red and green lettering invokes an emotional response that always draws attention and is hard to ignore. It'd be cool to see similar events there for accepted/rejected flags and suggested edits.

Good idea, ill edit the request.
